# krunner high CPU load

Tags: kde, cpu-load, krunner

For quite some time I've been having issue with krunner that it causes high ~95%) CPU load. I have indexing turned off as it also was an issue but that didn't help eventually.

Any ideas on how to analyze the issue?

Regards,
Artur

Comment: KDE bug tracker: https://bugs.kde.org. Maybe 
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=377715 and https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=375500

Comment: If you click on the icon to the left of the krunner text box, you could reduce the scope of what krunner does. See if that helps. For example, I have `enabledCategories=Applications,Document,Folder,Image,Locations,Places,Plasma Desktop Shell,Recent Documents,System Settings,Terminate Applications` and don't experience high CPU load because of krunner.

Comment: I have: command line, document, folder, kwin, locations, places, plasma desktop shell, power, recent documents, system settings, terminate applications unit converter, windows.

I'll check if reducing the plugins to the ones you have enabled helps. It isn't, however, solution to the problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Form removing software center from enabled categories solved the issue